# Организация работы с кодом для последующей сборки, автоматизации

Tags: c#, git, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть солюшен, который содержит в себе различные проекты. Задача: реализовать версионирование в рамках солюшена/проектов. Данное действие видется так:

- Версионирование каждого проекта в отдельности;
- Версионирование солюшена в целом, как совокупность содержимого.

Реализация: организация работы с **VCS** на основе **git tag** и соответствующих веток, для отметки версии того или иного проекта. Что-то вроде **Git-Flow**.

Имеем ветку **X** в которой будет вестись разработка дополнительного функционала той или иной части проекта и по окончанию работы над которым создается тег, например **Project_N_v.1.1**. Далее происходит слияние с веткой **Y**, которая так же помечается соответствующей версией.

После этого планируется использовать версии из меток при сборке/создании пакетов и чего бы то не было еще. На данном этапе не понято:

- Как должным образом извлекать нужную информацию из коммитов?
- Вменяем ли описанный подход в целом?
- Имеет ли смысл вписывать версию руками при работе над проектом (**AssemblyInfo**)?
- Что можно использовать для автоматизации процесса?

**UPD**. В данный момент сборка реализована с помощью **CakeBuild**, который запускается по тригеру из Bamboo. Соответственно работа будет происходить внутри **CakeBuild**.

**UPD1**. В добавок ко всему возникла необходимость разделить солюшен на части. Частей предвидится много, поэтому для удобства работы решено использовать **git-submodules**. Т.е разносим проекты из солюшена в отдельные репозитории и имеем возможность работать с ним так же как и раньше, т.е один родительский репозиторий и дочерние.

Выбор такого подхода сопряжен с тем, что имеется потребность в версионировании множества проектов в рамках отдельно взятого солюшена. Так как из **git-submodules** проекты являются отдельными репозиториями, то можно в каждом из них создавать **git tag** с версией. В случае разнесения проектов без **git-submodules** теряется такая возможность и остается вариант с занесением версии в **AssemblyInfo**, но в таком случае версии не попадают в **VCS** и теряется возможность перемещения по ним.

Далее имеем три типа "*релиза*": **develop**, **pre-prod**, **prod**. Для **develop** ничего дополнильного к вышесказанному не надо, разнесли проект, работаем по **git-flow**, ставим **git tag** для последующего версионирования. В случае с **pre-prod**, **prod** в дело включается **NuGet**, который после сборки проекта будет получать версию пакетов на основании **git tag** соответствующего проекта.

Собственно вопрос сводится не столько к версионированию, как отмечено в заголовке, а к организации процесса. Какие минусы такого подхода? Альтернатива?

Comment: Чем обычный gitflow не устроил? Для чего эти сложности?

Comment: Вместо коммитов лучше использовать тэги, оно для этого идеально сгодятся.

Comment: @tym32167 Не корректно выразился. Путаюсь в терминалогии. Не коммиты, а метки. Да. Использую метки для выделения версий и т.п. На деле и будет Git-Flow. Проблема в том, что я не очень понимаю как сопоставлять версии и проекты в солюшине.

Comment: @Monk, они и подразумевались. Не правильно выразился.

Comment: А в чем вы видите профит от версионирования каждого проекта в отдельности? Спрашиваю, так как работал с солюшенами раскиданными по разным репам и получал только неудобства от этого

Comment: @tym32167, какое решение в противовес? Версионировать солюшен как совокупность содержимого? Допустим есть два проекта, которые зависят от какого-то другого и так сложилось, что они нуждаются в конкретных версиях третьего. Как разрешить этот сценарий? Если мне надо NuGet пакеты собирать? Как я их в итоге буду версионировать?

Comment: Мы держали nuget пакеты отдельными солюшенами, отдельными репами, отдельно версионировали. Код nuget пакетов никак не зависел от кода проектов, которые его использовали.

Comment: Я не знаю, как у вас разделено по проектам, но обычно в проектах, где я работал, каждый сервис был независимым и хранился в отдельной репе, каждый пакет также независим и в репе. Таким образом, если какая то фича вовлекала несколько слабо связанных сервисов/пакетов, то она была как бы историей с несколькими тасками внутри - отдельная таска по каждому сервису/пакету

Comment: Попахивает jenkins. Возможно такое можно реализовать и в cakebuild.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к мнению tym32167. Собирайте проекты в nuget-пакеты на сборочном сервере типа team city. Не вижу смысла использовать субмодули для подобных задач.